# Can't run tests for Android in the debug mode after change port

Tags: detox

I want to create E2E tests for Android. I went through [this guide](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/introduction/android/).

- run build with configaration - detox build -c android.emu.staging.debug -> get success build apk.
- After it, run react-native start --port=8087 (Can't use default port, because it busy security programm McAfee)
- Run test with configuration - detox test -c android.emu.staging.debug
- After run test have error
  [image]
  (Tests have already started running and **wait device.lauchApp()** )
- Then with Ctrl + M change bundle and set 10.0.2.2:8087
  [image]
- After it bundle start building -> Success build.
- And then stuck on launchApp and get timeout error.

Tell please, how can I run test on different ports ?

I find the same issue https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/3190 and set bundleInDebug: true helped me, but i think it's the wrong direction.

#### Your environment

Detox version: 17.14.3
React Native version: 0.66.0
Node version: 14.15.5
Device model: Android Emulator Pixel 2 API 30
OS: Windows
Test-runner (select one): jest-circus / jest+jasmine / mocha / other
jest

I try run detox debug test on other port, because of default port (8081) is busy by other program.

Comment: Could you please try the following: go into `Settings` -> `Debug server host and port for device` and input the address there and after that `reload`.  Does it manage to now read from the packager? 

Also, have you done `adb reverse` for the port? e.g. `adb reverse tcp:8087 tcp:8087`

Comment: @Jon Thank you for advice, unfortunately no change, test still stucks. After  Settings -> Debug server host and port for device and reload I have success build, then did reverse for the port and have same timeout error and stuck on launchApp.

Comment: Running `detox test` likely restarts the app, which might make your previous settings scarce (except for "adb reverse", which affect the emulator). @Jon has a trick to automate the injection of localhost:8087 setting.

Comment: One more t hing to consider is to run the tests in release mode, which is anyways more highly recommended by us

Answer (score 0):

With help detox team got the following solution - https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/3279

For me all work correct in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the full answer here as well in the hopes that it may help someone out.

Locate your DetoxTest.java file, see guide and insert the following lines:

At the top of the class:

```
private static final String RN_DEBUG_HOST_KEY = "debug_http_host";
```

and inside the runDetoxTests method:

```
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();

SharedPreferences preferences =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
preferences.edit().putString(RN_DEBUG_HOST_KEY, "localhost:8087").apply();

DetoxConfig detoxConfig = new DetoxConfig();
detoxConfig.rnContextLoadTimeoutSec = 500;
```

and finally pass the detoxConfig as the third argument to runTests. E.g.:

```
Detox.runTests(rule, context, detoxConfig);
```

You will also have to reverse the port - you can do this either manually from the commandline, or by putting the following code inside the beforeAll of your tests:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.reverseTcpPort(8087);
}
```